# cin skips over the next cin only when a non-numeric value is entered

Tags: c++

The following code works as intended when it is given 2 integers, however if a non numeric value (like 'a') is given, it skips the second cin.

```
int num1;   // lesser integer value input by user
int num2;  // greater integer value input by user

cout << "\n\nNumber 1: ";
cin >> num1;


cout << "Number 2: ";
cin >> num2;

if (!cin)
{
    cout <<"\nError" <<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

When entering a number for the first prompt the program carries on, however if something like `a` is entered for the first prompt, it skips the second prompt and hits the error condition

Comment: What would you expect? There was an error, you got error condition. Also, there is still 'a' at the beginning of the input.

Comment: Didn't quite understand the error cases for cin. The current top answer helped clear that up. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the formatted input operator `>>` fails (like for example you give `a` as input when a number was expected) the input in the buffer is not removed, it's still there for the next time you want to read input (which will attempt to read the very same `a` again).

The flags are also not cleared automatically.

You could solve this by checking when you read the input:

```
if (!(std::cin >> num1))
{
    // Failure of some kind
    if (std::cin.eof())
    {
        // End of file, handle this any way you like or need
    }
    else
    {
        // Not end-of-file
        std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n'); // Skip bad input
        std::cin.clear();  // Clear error flags
    }
}
```

References:

- [`operator>>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/operator_gtgt)
- [`ignore`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/ignore)
- [`clear`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/clear)

Answer (score 0):

This means your input validation is failed. 
The process of checking whether user input conforms to what the program is expecting is called input validation.
5 is int and a is char.

```
char a;
cout << "\n\nYour Char ";
cin >> a;
```

Will work